# Float encryption with Jasypt issue

Tags: java, oracle, floating-point, bigdecimal, jasypt

I need to encrypt float values and I am using Jasypt to achive this.

As far as I know, Jasypt does not support float encryption and only supports BigDecimal. Therefore, I am converting float values to BigDecimal.

The conversion is done successfully. Also the encryption and decryption using Jasypt.

However, when I persist the encrypted value into the Oracle DB, the value is changed in the DB.

Example of values that I need to persist as it is:

-6542850164453273769179743775075308980128742113.12
-4139490689573544701682206282760323584523816140.64
9936653106931456268018508106437020093773774849.6
-69457501008740608752977363196163239676824308939.2
-512974351190591202428175056439128604458367.320048

I am using Number data type in the oracle.

The questionis, how to save the above values without allowing the DB to change them?

The DB always remove the ( . ) from the value and adds zeros

This value 689612971966376606053641908553771273056281.427984 is saved as:
-217333936122185596255723452297898520757000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

You're relying on the number coming out of the database being *exactly* the same as the number you put in - and while it seems very odd for you to get exactly the results you're getting (in terms of negation) I'm not wholly surprised that it doesn't work in general. You would have to pick your database type *really* carefully to get the exact value out again - in particular, it would have to have as much precision as the results of the encryption.

It's also not clear whether the encryption relies on the scale of the `BigDecimal` (i.e. where 1.0 and 1.00 are represented differently). I don't know whether you'll persuade the database to preserve the scale information.

I would strongly advise you to use more normal encryption mechanisms - basically encrypt to binary data, store it as a blob of some kind in the database, and the decrypt from the blob to the original data. You're much less likely to run into subtle representation problems storing a blob in a database than performing floating point to fixed point conversions.

Comment: Converting to binary is not encryption. I need real encryption not only converting.

Comment: @Nabeel: I wasn't talking about *just* converting to binary - I was talking about normal encryption mechanisms, where the result *is* opaque binary data. That's why I talked about encrypting and decrypting - why did you think I meant simple "plain" conversions?

Comment: Ok, but the problem is, that I need to have number datatype in the DB. If I am allowed to change the data type, I would use VARCHAR which will definitely store any thing as it is.

Comment: @Nabeel: VARCHAR would still be an inappropriate type, as it's text rather than binary. So if you're limited to NUMBER, what *exact* type is it? What scale etc? Note that you may need to use multiple values per original source value, in order to ensure that the data can be recovered correctly...

Comment: I would convert the string coming from VARCHAR to number in the application layer, using Java.

I am stucked with this issue! Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

A Java `float` is an IEEE-754 floating-point number that uses 32 bits of storage.

We can dump these bits into a Java `int` which is conveniently 32 bits wide, and we can also convert the `int` back to a float: [Float.floatToIntBits()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToIntBits%28float%29), [Float.intBitsToFloat()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat%28int%29).

Note that the `int` may be positive or negative; it has the range [−(2<sup>31</sup>), (2<sup>31</sup>) − 1].

Jasypt provides a way to [encrypt `BigInteger`s](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/apidocs/org/jasypt/util/numeric/IntegerNumberEncryptor.html), so we can convert the `int` to a `BigInteger`, encrypt that, and store it in the database.

Here's a sketch of the encryption code:

```
float x = (... my float value ...);
IntegerNumberEncryptor enc = (... an instance from somewhere ...);

int temp0 = Float.floatToIntBits(x);
BigInteger temp1 = BigInteger.valueOf(temp0);
BigInteger result = enc.encrypt(temp1);
(... store result in database ...)
```

And a sketch of the decryption code:

```
BigInteger input = (... get encrypted number from database ...)
IntegerNumberEncryptor enc = (... an instance from somewhere ...)

BigInteger temp0 = enc.decrypt(input);
int temp1 = temp0.intValue();
float result = Float.intBitsToFloat(temp1);
(... now do something with result ...)
```

Comment: @Jon Skeet : Unfortunately, this didn't help that much.
You cannot say Float.floatToIntBits(689612971966376606053641908553771273056281.427984f);
Because that number is out of range.

How can I represent that number in Java or Oracle? It can't be stored in Float/float, neither Integer/int.